# Why is a pointer mismatch allowed for a recursive typedef?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I've been learning C on learn-c.org

After covering the unit regarding typedef declarations and structs. They finished with what they called "a recursive definition of a linked list" I found fairly straightforward, except for what seems like a mismatched pointer....

```
typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
}node_t

// usage

node_t* head = NULL;
head = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->val = 1;
head->next = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->next->val = 2;
head->next->next = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->next->next->val = 3;
```

My understanding is, by supplying `typedef struct node`, we are able to declare the node pointer `next` within the structure.

My confusion occurs on line 11. We are dynamically allocating memory for our next node, but we cast the void pointer as a `node_t` pointer, not a `node` pointer -- despite that fact that `head->next` is a `(node*)` type. Why is this allowed? Is C simply just recasting to a `(node*)` behind the scenes, and `(node_t*)` is used for readability?

Comment: They're the same type?

Comment: The typedef makes `struct node` and `node_t` equivalent. So `struct node*` is the same as `node_t*`.

Comment: There's no such thing as `(node*)`, only `(struct node*)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typedef` makes `node_t` equivalent to `struct node`, so anywhere you might use `struct node` you can use the shorter `node_t` instead. So `(node_t*)` is equivalent to `(struct node*)`.

The one exception is inside the structure declaration itself, because the name being defined isn't usable until *after* the `typedef` statement (just as you can't use a function or variable before they're declared).

BTW, it's not necessary to cast the result of `malloc()`. It returns `void*`, and C allows this to be assigned to any pointer type without an explicit cast. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/)

Comment: To your knowledge, is a canonical stance for typecasting void*; or does it really come down to personal preference?

Comment: Most of the experts here recommend against it, for the reasons given in the question I linked to.